# Leaflet marker HTML for legend dialog

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I am using Bootstrap and Leaflet with `Leaflet.awesome-markers` for different types of objects on the map.

How can I implement Bootstrap modal window with legend? Where can I get the HTML used for map marker? Is there any method I can call on `L.AwesomeMarkers.icon()` to get the HTML and append it to modal dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Icon method `createIcon()` which returns the marker HTML.

Comment: It is not documented, I digged it from the sources.